# SQL Modify Column Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to go through an entire column of datetime data and modify the year so that they're all 2016.  I have a customer that decided to modify my code and it broke the math that calculates the current date and time.  So now, they see years 2016, 2116, 2216, etc.  Anyway, what I am looking for is some script that will go through a column and if the last four digits of the column aren't 2016, replace the last four digits with 2016 while the beginning data remains intact.

I.e. If the date is xx/xx/2116, change it to xx/xx/2016.

Comment: Is the column a `datetime` or a `varchar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `STUFF`:

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET SomeColumn = STUFF(SomeColumn,LEN(SomeColumn)-3,4,'2016')
WHERE RIGHT(SomeColumn,4) <> '2016';
```

Comment: Perfect!  One more:  There are about 30K cells where the date is '582016'.  I need to trunc that to just 2016.

Comment: @Addohm `SET SomeColumn = '2016' WHERE SomeColumn = '582016'`?

Comment: That would only look for 2016 wouldn't it?  The columns are xx/xx/582016.

Comment: well, you said different in your comment: `I need to trunc '582016' to just 2016`

Comment: Anyway, it's essentially the same answer I already posted: `SET SomeColumn = STUFF(SomeColumn,LEN(SomeColumn)-5,6,'2016') WHERE RIGHT(SomeColumn,6) <> '582016';`

Comment: Sorry.  I was building on the original post, or so I thought!  I need to keep the xx/xx/ but change 582016 to 2016.

Comment: Did you mean `WHERE RIGHT(Snapshot_Date,6) = '582016'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124658/discussion-between-addohm-and-lamak).

Comment: @Addohm I don't know the actual name of your column, that's why I used `SomeColumn`. And yes, it should've been = '582016'

Comment: Oh I know that.  I meant to ask, wouldn't that particular bit of code change every column that is NOT 582016?

Answer (score 0):

If it is `datetime` datatype you can use DATEADD and DATEDIFF:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET DateColumn = DATEADD(YEAH,DATEDIFF(YEAR,DateColumn,GETDATE()),DateColumn)
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR,GETDATE(),DateColumn) != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your column is a datetime column.

If so, you can use the following code:

```
DECLARE @ChangeToYear VARCHAR(4) = '2016'

UPDATE TableToBeChanged 
SET DateFieldToConvert =
    (SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, @ChangeToYear - YEAR(DateFieldToConvert), DateFieldToConvert))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update YourTable
Set YourDate = Dateadd(year, 2016 - year(YourDate), YourDate)
Where Year(YourDate) <> 2016
```